# Results incomplete from jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, symfony1, autocomplete

I'm using the jquery autocomplete plugin for displaying a list of cities to the user.
I'm working with the Symfony 1.4 framework with Doctrine.
I have a table with all the cities name.

When the user start entering a city name in the concerned input, i'm doing this SQL query :

```
    $q = $this->createQuery('v')
     ->where('v.name like ?', $string.'%')
     ->orderBy('v.name')
     ->limit($limit)
     ->execute();
```

where $string is the string entered by the user and $limit the limit configured in the plugin.

In my table, there are several cities with the same name and I only see one of them in the results...

When I copy the query in phpmyadmin, I see all the results...

If anyone has a clue, it'd be very appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('v')
 ->where('v.name like ?', '%'.$string.'%')
 ->orderBy('v.name')
 ->limit($limit)
 ->execute();
```